# flvjs - Check if flv is avaiable / Check if flv stream ended

Tags: javascript, flv, streaming-flv-video, flvplayer

I got a small question about flvjs. How can I check if a flv file is avaiable using flv and how can I check if a flv stream ended? In total how can I listen to events (flv.js)? I didn't really understand it.

`flvjs.on('ERROR', () => { console.log("Stream over")         });`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [this article](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041163719/en). Try as: `yourflvPlayer.on( flvjs.Events.ERROR , (err, errdet) => { console.log( "test message" ); }`